# How to set Terraform workspace variables via CLI?

Tags: variables, command-line-interface, terraform

I'm using workspaces in terraform to separate environments at runtime, so that I can separate deployments using a different configs.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to set CLI variables.

my variables.tf:

```
locals {
  environment     = "${terraform.workspace}"
  lambda_vars = {
    deploy_version        = "0.1"
    deploy_name           = "deployment"
    deploy_secret_1       = "somesupersecretsecret"
  }
}
```

These variables are used throughout my config.

I'm trying to set new variables using the CLI, but it doesnt work, and I can't seem to find any reference to how to achieve this. I've tried:

```
terraform apply -var 'local.lambda_vars={ deploy_secret_1 = "somesupersecretsecret1" }'
```

I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to configure the variables then you should use actual [variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) instead of [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html). Locals are a way of composing things so you avoid repeating yourself or can use interpolation. Variables don't allow for any interpolation at all.

So in your case you should declare separate variables for things you want to be able configure. If this is just the `deploy_secret_1` then you can do this with something like the following:

```
variable "deploy_secret_1" {
  default = "somesupersecretsecret"
}

locals {
  environment = terraform.workspace

  lambda_vars = {
    deploy_version  = "0.1"
    deploy_name     = "deployment"
    deploy_secret_1 = var.deploy_secret_1
  }
}
```

Now if you run the following command:

```
terraform apply -var 'deploy_secret_1=overriding-secret'
```

It should overwrite the `deploy_secret_1` part but leave the rest as is. If you don't specify the `deploy_secret_1` variable either by the command line, environment variables or a `tfvars` file then it will default to `somesupersecretsecret`. If you'd rather force it to be defined and error if you don't specify the variable then just omit the `default` argument to the variable declaration.

If you wanted to be able to override more things then you should declare more variables.